# How to return all the intere connected multiple items from a Django model using a query set?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

I have a data like shown below, first column protein IDs second column peptide sequence and third column some value I have created a Django model to store this data.

Data table:

```
A0A075B6K4  YELTQPPSVSTAR   60,10
A0A075B6K4  SYELTQPPSVTAR   2
A0A075B6Q5  EVQLVESGEGSLR   7
A0A075B6S5  DIQMTQSPSGDR    10
A0A0A0MRZ8  EIVLTQSPGER 30,20
A0A0B4J1V0  EVQLVESGGSLR    10
A0A0B4J1X5  EVQLVESGGSLR    0
A0A0B4J2D9  AIQLTQSPSGDR    0
A0A0C4DH42  EVQLVESGGSLR    0
A0A0C4DH55  EIVMTQSPGER 10
A0A0C4DH42  YELTQPPSTAR 20
A0A0C4DH55  YELTQPPSTAR 4
A0A0B4J1X5  YELTQPPSTAR 12
```

Django models:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.


class ProteinID(models.Model):
    ProtID = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % (self.ProtID)

class PeptideSeq(models.Model):
    sequence = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    feq = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    protein = models.ForeignKey(ProteinID, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.sequence, self.feq)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['sequence']
```

**Details:**

As we can see in the table a single protein ID can hold more then one peptide sequence and single peptide can be associated with more then one protein ID.

I want to add two search option:

1. if a protein ID entered as a query it should return all the associated peptides and the values from the third column

Query A0A0C4DH55 should return

```
YELTQPPSTAR 4
EIVMTQSPGER 10
```

2. Or a peptide sequence entered as a query it should return all the associated protein id and values from the third column.

Query EVQLVESGGSLR should return

```
A0A0B4J1V0 10
A0A0B4J1X5 0
A0A0C4DH42 0
```

How to I implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of making proteinID a foreign key in your peptide Model, establish a many to many relationship between Protein and Peptide Models. That way, a protein will have multiple peptides and a peptide can belong to many proteins.

You can get all peptides related to a protein like this

```
protein = ProteinID.objects.get(ProtID=1)
peptides = protein.peptide_set.all()
```

Same way you can get the protein of a sine peptide as well.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 1):

1.
`ProteinID.objects.get(id='A0A0C4DH55').peptideseq_set.all()`

2.
`PeptideSeq.objects.filter(sequence='EVQLVESGGSLR').values('protein__ProtID', feq)`